# SQLAlchemy - AmbiguousForeignKeysError despite using the 'foreignkeys=' argument

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm creating an application that uses SQLAlchemy, but keep running into the
following error:

```
AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between 
parent/child tables on relationship Team.home_matches
 - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables. 
Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those
 columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference
 to the parent table.
```

I've applied the solution provided in the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths), (setting the `foreign_keys` attribute) but this did not solve the problem and the error keeps returning.

The error occurs between these two models: 
The idea is that the database will contain a table with results from different soccer matches and a table that contains the different teams.

```
class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(length=250), unique=True)
    home_matches = relationship("Match", back_populates='home')
    away_matches = relationship("Match", back_populates='away')

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

```
class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'matches'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    home_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('teams.id'))
    home = relationship(
        "Team", back_populates='home_matches', foreign_keys=[home_id]
    )
    away_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('teams.id'))
    away = relationship(
        "Team", back_populates='away_matches', foreign_keys=[away_id]
    )
    home_score = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    away_score = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The relationships in `Team` do not use `foreign_keys=`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the assist!